# Why is the Bash "test" function not correctly identifying directories within this while loop?

Tags: bash

I have some code which is suprising me.  I'm hoping someone can answer me about the behavior of Bash's `test` function "[[ ]]".
The following function `cdlic` is intended to find the first matching subdirectory given a parent directory and a pattern and then `cd` into that directory.  I have disabled the `cd` command for testing.
At any rate, `cdloc foo bar` should find the first valid directory matching `foo/*bar*` and report it:

```bash
function cdloc () {
    local dir="${1}"
    local subdir="${2}"
    local found=""
    if isnull "${2}" ; then
        subdir=$(basename "${dir}")
        dir=$(dirname "${dir}")
    fi
    
    while read -r target ; do 
        echo "cdloc trying '${target}'"
        set -xv
        if [[ -d ${target} ]]; then 
            echo "cdloc: found matching directory '${target}'"
            #cd "${target}"
            # return 0
        else
            echo "cdloc: skipping non-directory '${target}'"
        fi
        set +xv
    done < <(ls -d "${dir}"/*"${subdir}"* 2>/dev/null)

    echo "Could not find match for dir \"${dir}\" and subdir \"${subdir}\", even using pattern matching"
}
```

- I ran a test case.

```bash
cook@MacBook-Pro-2021 (obsidian-image-resizer-plugin (BARE:master)): mkdir -p foo/bar
rcook@MacBook-Pro-2021 (obsidian-image-resizer-plugin (BARE:master)): cdloc foo bar
cdloc trying 'foo/bar/'
+(/Users/rcook/Projects/RC-bash-lib/shellfuncs.sh:13): cdloc(): [[ -d foo/bar/ ]]
+(/Users/rcook/Projects/RC-bash-lib/shellfuncs.sh:18): cdloc(): echo 'cdloc: skipping non-directory '\''foo/bar/'\'''
cdloc: skipping non-directory 'foo/bar/'
+(/Users/rcook/Projects/RC-bash-lib/shellfuncs.sh:20): cdloc(): set +xv
Could not find match for dir "foo" and subdir "bar", even using pattern matching
rcook@MacBook-Pro-2021 (obsidian-image-resizer-plugin (BARE:master)): 
# Wait what? 
rcook@MacBook-Pro-2021 (obsidian-image-resizer-plugin (BARE:master)): if [[ -d foo/bar/ ]] ;then echo yes; fi
yes
```

Why is the `[[ -d foo/bar/ ]]` test failing in the function when the same code seems to succeed when run outside the function?

- Interestingly, if I use "find" instead of "ls" it works:

```bash
function cdloc () {
    local dir="${1}"
    local subdir="${2}"
    local found=""
    if isnull "${2}" ; then
        subdir=$(basename "${dir}")
        dir=$(dirname "${dir}")
    fi
    
    while read -r target ; do 
        echo "cdloc trying '${target}'"
        #set -xv
        if [[ -d ${target} ]]; then 
            echo "cdloc: found matching directory '${target}'"
            cd "${target}"
            return 0
        else
            echo "cdloc: skipping non-directory '${target}'"
        fi
        #set +xv
    done < <(find "${dir}" -depth 1 -name "*${subdir}*" 2>/dev/null)


    echo "Could not find match for dir \"${dir}\" and subdir \"${subdir}\", even using pattern matching"
   
    return 1
    
}

rcook@MacBook-Pro-2021 (wealthyvault (master)): cdloc "$OBSIDIAN_DEV_DIR" resize
cdloc trying '/Volumes/2_TB_SSD_external/Projects_2TB/computers-and-geekery/projects and languages/Obsidian development/obsidian-image-resizer-plugin'
cdloc: found matching directory '/Volumes/2_TB_SSD_external/Projects_2TB/computers-and-geekery/projects and languages/Obsidian development/obsidian-image-resizer-plugin'
rcook@MacBook-Pro-2021 (obsidian-image-resizer-plugin (master)): pwd
/Volumes/2_TB_SSD_external/Projects_2TB/computers-and-geekery/projects and languages/Obsidian development/obsidian-image-resizer-plugin
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what’s going on there but note that it a mistake to parse the output of `ls`, and will give erroneous results for valid file names. You should use `find dir -maxdepth 1 -name "*${subdir}*" -type d -print0` instead (and replace `read -r target` with `IFS='' read -r -d '' target`). This will also make the `[[-d]]` test unnecessary.

Comment: but why not `for i in "${dir}"/*"${subdir}"*/`? Even `arr=("${dir}"/*"${subdir}"*/); if (( ${#arr[@]} )); then return 0; fi`

Comment: Yes, both `find dir -maxdepth 1 -name "*${subdir}*" -type d` and `for i in "${dir}"/*"${subdir}"*/` work, interestingly.  It's just the output of `ls` which is somehow funked up.  Weird.  I just can't let it go.  Why is it different specifically?

Comment: Tangentially, `test` is `[`, not `[[`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph by " it a mistake to parse the output of ls, and will give erroneous results for valid file names" do you mean that spaces in filenames are a problem, or what is the concern with parsing the output of ls?  Thanks

Comment: @Rich See [ParsingLs - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). And for more on that topic: [shell - Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

Comment: @Rich Spaces and special characters, e.g. newlines. In general, POSIX does not place *any* limitations on path names, except that they may not contain the zero-character. (Furthermore, the output format of `ls` isn’t fully specified, and different implementations format output slightly differently).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm willing to credit you as The Answer here but I think I can't if you just leave as a comment.  If you submit as an answer I'll validate it.  Else I'll quote you for the answer.  Cheers

Comment: @Rich Prefer KamilCuk's solution, it's plain bash, no need for external utilities like `find`.

Comment: What is `isnull`?

Comment: You aren't quoting inside `[[ -d ${target} ]]`, which is potentially a problem. You may also need to use GNU ls instead of the BSD version with `gls -Qd` if you want to ensure the output of each ls entry is quoted. And why not just `[[ -n "$2" ]]` instead of reinventhing it with `isnull`?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I believe you are thinking of single brackets.  Quoting is not needed in double brackets.  See section 3.6 here:  https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-single-vs-double-brackets. And the reason for having a function just do one simple thing is just so I could remember it back in the day and now it's all over my code, I don't even notice it.  Easy to remember "isnull" but hard to remember [[ -z $var ]] or whatever.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two good solutions

- Thanks to [kamilcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) and [konrad-rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph) for these.
- Both of these avoid using `ls`, which is known to cause problems in parsing its output.
- `dbecho` is basically echo
- `isnull` tests whether a string is empty

### Solution 1:  pure bash

```bash
# convenience function 
function cdloc () {
    local dir="${1}"
    local subdir="${2%/}"
    local found=""
    if isnull "${subdir}" ; then
        dir=$(dirname "${1}")
        subdir=$(basename "${1}")
    fi
    
    if [[ "${subdir}" =~ "/" ]]; then
        subdirA=${subdir%/*}
        subdirB=${subdir#*/}
        dir="${dir}/${subdirA}"
        subdir="${subdirB}"
    fi
    echovals dir subdir

    # ==================================================================
    # Pure bash solution, should be more efficient
    for target in "$dir"/*"${subdir}"*; do
        dbecho 1 "cdloc trying candidate '${target}'"
        #set -xv
        if cd "${target}"; then 
            dbecho 0 "changing directory to '${target}'"            
            #set +xv
            return 0
        else
            dbecho 1 "oops, not a directory: '${target}'"
        fi
        #set +xv
    done 

    echo "Could not find match for dir \"${dir}\" and subdir \"${subdir}\", even using pattern matching"
    return 1    
}
```

### Solution 2:  using find

```bash
# convenience function 
function cdloc () {
    local dir="${1}"
    local subdir="${2%/}"
    local found=""
    if isnull "${subdir}" ; then
        dir=$(dirname "${1}")
        subdir=$(basename "${1}")
    fi
    
    if [[ "${subdir}" =~ "/" ]]; then
        subdirA=${subdir%/*}
        subdirB=${subdir#*/}
        dir="${dir}/${subdirA}"
        subdir="${subdirB}"
    fi
    echovals dir subdir

    # ===================================================================
    # Using `find`
    while IFS='' read -r target ; do 
        dbecho 1 "cdloc trying candidate '${target}'"
        # set -xv
        # set +xv
        if cd "${target}"; then 
            dbecho 0 "changing directory to '${target}'"            
            return 0
        else
            dbecho 1 "oops, not a directory: '${target}'"
        fi
        set +xv
    done < <(find "${dir}/" -depth 1 -name "*${subdir}*" 2>/dev/null)
    # done < <(ls -d "$dir"/*"$subdir"* 2>/dev/null) # does not work for some reason

    echo "Could not find match for dir \"${dir}\" and subdir \"${subdir}\", even using pattern matching"
    return 1    
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. To emphasize never using `ls`, see [Bash Pitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) -- there is a reason that's `#1`. For full discussion, see also [Parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Simply `[[ $subdir ]]` also checks whether `$subdir` is non-empty. The braces add no value there.